# How to respect MVC in Swift?

Tags: swift, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I am wondering **how did you manage to correctly respect MVC design pattern on your IOS developments with Swift ?** What I feel right now is that a view controller mix both the controller part and the view part but it feels wrong right ? To respect MVC, we clearly need to separate the controller and the view. **How did you make this ?**
Maybe, it's more obvious with other design patterns like MVVM or MVP ?

Comment: Create custom views?

Comment: Stanford swift course explains very beautifully, how to implement in iOS applications. https://itunes.apple.com/in/course/developing-ios-10-apps-with-swift/id1198467120

Comment: Why are writing in the past tense?  "how did you manage to correctly respect MVC design pattern on your IOS developments with Swift ?"  When?  "How did you make this ?"  When?

Comment: Sorry english mistake

Answer (score 2):

You can separate your project and create a structure where you have all the logic and models in one place and all the viewControllers in one place.

Like this for example:

```
Core
    Models
        Person.swift
        Car.swift
    Helpers
        Extensions.swift
        APIHelper.swift
    Webservice
        Webservice.swift


Controllers
    ViewController.swift
    SecondViewController.swift
```

So you basically have all the logics and calculations in your `Core` and all the views and UI elements in your `Controllers`. With this way you won´t have to do the same logic code multiple times. You could also create custom views and add them to your `Core` which you later can call in your `Controllers`.

Comment: Please note that is an updated version of the traditional MVC, which is called MVC-N.

Answer (score 2):

*Although it might be too broad to answer such a question, I will answer your specific issue about:*

> view controller mix both the controller part and the view part...

Note that when working an iOS project, it leads you implicitly to apply the [MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) pattern. By default, the view controllers represent the `Controller` part, the *.storyboard* and *.xib* files represent the `View` part and any model objects for encapsulating the data (data templates) represents the `Model`.

> What I feel right now is that *a view controller mix both the*
>   *controller part and the view part* but it feels wrong right ?

The view controller has *many* responsibilities to be handled, in addition to interprets user actions, it should also have to be the intermediary between view and the model(s), and don't forget about handling the integration with web services... That's the issue of the *Massive View Controller*.

if you tried to do some researches about solving this issue, you would find many approaches to follow such as applying other structural patterns like *MVVM*, *MVP* , *VIPER* or *Clean Architecture* or even simpler approaches such as dividing your project files to increase the jobs independency which leads to make it more clear and easy to trace, *MVC-N* might be a good example.

But for the specific case that are you asking about (mix both the controller part and the view part) to keep it simple: I would recommend to separate the logic of the data representation based on its view, example:

One of the most popular case when building an iOS project is working with table view and its cells, consider the following:

**ViewController.swift:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // ...
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myDataSourceArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCellID") as! MyCustomCell

        // ...

        return cell
    }
}
```

**MyCustomCell.swift:**

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblMessage: UILabel!
}
```

Now, imagine that -somehow- there is a requirement to change the `lblMessage` label text color in the cell based on a bunch of *complex* calculations, for such a case:

Do *not* do this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCellID") as! MyCustomCell

    // do calulations which might needs tens of lines to be achieved, based on that:
    cell.lblMessage.textColor = UIColor.red

    return cell
}
```

That leads to make the view controller to be massive and contains alot of jobs, instead do:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCellID") as! MyCustomCell

    //...

    cell.doCalaulations()

    return cell
}
```

In the cell class:

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblMessage: UILabel!

    func doCalaulations() {
        // do calulations which might needs tens of lines to be achieved, based on that:
        blMessage.textColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```

That leads to make the project components to be more encapsulated and the important thing is the view controller does *not* has to take care of the whole thing. For me, in cases that similar to this one, I would prefer to even make `blMessage` to be `private` which guarantees to make it only editable from the owner class (more encapsulation) to handle any needed behavior, thus any view controller should call the class methods instead of direct accessing to its properties and its IBOutlets.

Comment: So you recommend for any Outlets owned by a certain class to make it private to ensure (and force you) to call the class methods and avoid Massive controller issue right ?

Comment: I won't say it is *always* 100% is right, but for most of the time yes. FYI, if you ever download a sample code from Apple, you would see this approach is applied.

Comment: Never noticed that ^^ I will check that on same examples.

Comment: Great answer. MVC justified.

Answer (score 1):

Separate a usual `ViewController` on two different parts: `View` and `Presenter`. `View` responses only for displaying data and collecting user's interaction. `Presenter` prepares data for view and process user actions comes from `View`.

This idea came from [Clean Architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) by uncle Bob and realized into [VIPER](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/) architecture.

`View` has two protocols:

- `ViewInput` : contains functions for pass data to display like `set(labelText: String)`. This protocol should implement `View`. `Presenter` has object of type `ViewInput`.
- `ViewOutput` : contains functions, which calls when some events happen in view like `viewDidLoad()` or `rowDidSelect(at: IndexPath)`. This protocol should implement `Presenter`. `View` has object of type `ViewOutput`.

VIPER isn't trivial thing, I spent several days to understand its principles. So read articles and try to implement it in your code. Do not hesitate to ask questions.

Comment: I don't understand the "This protocol should implement Presenter." Meaning Presenter needs to implement ViewOutput protocol right ?

Comment: Yes, it is. For example, presenter should setup UI before display view.  So, in  `View` `viewDidLoad()` will call `presenter.didLoad()`. In `presenter.didLoad` will be call `set(label1Text: "first")`

Comment: Alright I have to try in my further developments to respect that If I feel it more clean. And View is a view controller right ?

Comment: You can read VIPER Book by rambler.This book has many answers for questions, which can appear https://github.com/strongself/The-Book-of-VIPER/tree/master/english .

Comment: The question was "how to respect MVC", why are you talking about VIPER ?